# Setting the output onclick for a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I wrote this

```
<form method="post" id="create">
  <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <p>Create a new Wall Post</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <textarea cols="80" id="text" name="text" rows="10" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>

      <script>
        $('#text').wysibb(options);
      </script>

      <div class="pull-right">
        <br>
        <button onclick="$('#text').val($('#text').htmlcode())" type="submit" name="create" class="btn btn-success">Post</button>
        <button type="reset" name="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


  <?php
  if (isset($_REQUEST['create'])) {
      $p = WallPostManager::createWallPost($user, UserManager::isLoggedIn(), $_POST['text']);

      if ($p != false) {
          Utils::alert("News Post created", false);
          header('refresh: 1');
      }
  }
```

But for some reason, im getting the 'text' in bbcode when im specifying it to be on .htmlcode(), what could be happening? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: htmlcode() is not a jQuery function... can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish with that onclick code?

Comment: @nthall `.htmlcode()` is a function from the plugin he's using: http://www.wysibb.com/docs/p9.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#text').htmlcode()
```

Doesn't work since that is not a jQuery function, as @nthall mentioned. Try changing it to

```
$('#text').html()
```

Comment: `.htmlcode()` is a function from the plugin he's using: http://www.wysibb.com/docs/p9.html